# 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token x in JSON at position 1' when trying to parse HTML embeded string JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I've being trying to parse a hardcoded JSON string to an usable format, but I can't find a way to get it work, getting 'Unexpected token' or just weird outputs. Library used: **jQuery**. The data to be stored is:

```
x:10
y,10
```

and

```
x:200
y:10
```

It's stored in a `data` attribute called `data-pos`, and I've tried multiple solutions, listed below:

- **Token error results (all combinations)**:

***Used functions***

```
JSON.parse(data);
$.parseJSON(data);
jQuery.parseJSON(data);
```

***Data formats***

```
data-pos="{'x':10,'y':10}"
data-pos="{'x':'10','y':'10}"
data-pos="{x:'10',y:'10'}"
data-pos="{x:10,y:10}"
```

- **Just weird output (no parsing)**:

***Used functions***

```
alert(data);
    --> output: 
        !!DATA AS IS!!
        !!DATA AS IS!!

alert ('x: ' + data.x + ' y: ' + data.y); /* Using {x: 200, y: 10} format */
    --> outputs:
        x: undefined y: undefined
        x: {y'    <-- Yep, THIS. No typos. IDK what the hell is going on.
```

***Data formats***

```
data-pos="{'x':10,'y':10}"
data-pos="{'x':'10','y':'10}"
data-pos="{x:'10',y:'10'}"
data-pos="{x:10,y:10}"
```

**Sourcefile:**

```
<html>    
    <head>
        <script>var devmode = true</script>
        <script>var loadExec=false</script>
        <script src="/files/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body id="body" class="selectable nooverflow">
        <div class="container hidden desktop">
            <div class="window selectable"  data-pos=!!DATA!!>
                <div class="titlebar">
                    <span class="titletext" onmousedown="movingW=true" onmouseup="movingW=false">Window 1</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="window" data-pos=!!DATA!!> 
                <div class="titlebar">
                    <span class="titletext" onmousedown="movingW=true" onmouseup="movingW=false">Window 2</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/files/css/style.css">
        <script src="/files/js/core.js"></script>       <!-- irrelevant -->
        <script src="/files/js/subcore.js"></script>    <!-- irrelevant -->
        <script>        
            $(function () {
                $(window).on("load", function () {
                    $('.window').each(function (index) {
                        if (!loadExec) {
                            var data = $(this).data('pos');
                            //alert(data + "\nDatatype: " + (typeof data));
                            if (data) {
                                alert(data);

                                //PARSING HERE!! <----------

                                $(this).css({ 'top': data.y, 'left': data.x, position: 'absolute' });
                            }

                            loadExec = true;
                            $('.container').removeClass('hidden');
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I've been searching but all I could find was unsuccesfull or ajax orientated. I just need to embed this JSON string in an attribute or some inside-DOM way. I just can't find the solution.

**THANKS FOR YOUR TIME!**

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In JSON, quotes must be **double** quotes, and all property names must be strings (e.g., in quotes), so none of the data formats you listed is correct. This would be correct:

```
data-pos='{"x":10,"y":10}'
```

or if it's important to put the attribute value in double quotes, since the content of attributes is HTML text (something people tend to forget), you *could* use `&quot;`:

```
data-pos="{&quot;x&quot;:10,&quot;y&quot;:10}"
```

...but only do that if you absolutely have to use `"` instead of `'` around the attribute value.

For details about JSON, including the fact that strings and property names must be in double quotes, refer to [the JSON website](http://json.org).

Examples:

```js
console.log("a's data:", $("#a").data("pos"));
console.log("b's data:", $("#b").data("pos"));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="a" data-pos='{"x":10,"y":10}'></div>
<div id="b" data-pos="{&quot;x&quot;:10,&quot;y&quot;:10}"></div>
```

Comment: That did it. Right now I'm feeling stupid. IDK why I didn't think of it. Thanks!

BTW, I'm impressed by the quick response (less than a minute!). Such wow!